# Why does my brand new faucet cartridge leak from the handle when turned on?

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet, cartridge

I recently replaced the ceramic cartridge in my bathroom faucet. However, the new cartridge leaks from the top when the water is turned on. Could anyone advise me on what I might have done wrong/what might be going on here?

Here's [a video of the leak](https://imgur.com/a/a62PJNQ) in case it helps.

Thank you!

[image]

Edit: Thank you to all who have replied. I'm adding pictures of both cartridges. The original is the tan Sedal brand cartridge, the replacement is the blue generic cartridge. I unfortunately have been unable to find the same Sedal cartridge available where I live (Poland).
I've also included a photo of the faucet, in case it helps. The faucet is an Omnires brand faucet.

Photos: https://imgur.com/a/LOWbTIN

Comment: The cartridge looks faulty. I expected to see water coming around it, not through it. Did it seem like it seated ok?

Comment: I had the same thought - but this is actually the second replacement cartridge I've installed. The previous new cartridge had the exact same problem, so I ordered a different one from a different manufacturer. Do you think they could both be faulty? 
It seems seated fine, and no leaking from the sides, just through it.

Comment: Then we're looking at either incorrect orientation or the wrong part.

Comment: In that case, I think it must be an incorrect part, because I don't think it could be an incorrect orientation. There are a couple of "feet" for lack of a better term that fit into the bottom of the faucet, so it can only fit one way. I'll see if I can find a better replacement. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you like, revise to mention your faucet and cartridge details and we'll help verify. Otherwise, please delete your post. Abandoned questions are ugly. Take the [tour] to learn more.

Comment: Ceramic cartridges can be easily damaged - if these are ceramic, installation error could be the cause.

Comment: As per isherwood's suggestion about cartridge details: if you didn't throw away the original one, a photograph of it would be great.

Comment: Thanks isherwood! I have updated the post with further details and photos of the cartridges. 
Greg, thank you for the response. It is completely possible that it is due to installation error. This is my first time replacing such a cartridge. Would you have any guess as to what I might be doing wrong in the install to cause this kind of damage?